# Is a specialized hardware instruction always faster than a software implementation, and if so, is there a general reason?

Tags: algorithms, performance, instruction-set

I started wondering this after reading about the x86-SSE instruction `rsqrtss` being faster (and more accurate) than the Fast inverse square root. I have also read about other specialized hardware instructions that replaced staple software algorithms for better performance. Can a specialized hardware instruction generally be designed to be more efficient than the most optimized software algorithm? I'm entirely ignorant about how hardware or compilers work, so I'm hoping for a very "for dummies" answer; right now I'm imagining the hardware has to do *some* algorithm, but custom circuit magic saves time compared to an equivalent software code compiled to a sequence of less specialized hardware instructions.

Comment: With contemporary "synchronous" execution units, *one clock cycle* would seem to be the absolute lower bound. (Predictably, the details are dirtier than that.) The amount of functions with a "combinatorial"(/combinational, "logic gates without feed-back", only) implementation that fast keeps increasing. The caveat is that *implementations of* special purpose instructions sometimes are slower than an equivalent sequence of simple ones. I remember examples from *procedure call frame handling* and *integer division*.

Comment: So uh, couldn't they implement a specialized instruction as a sequence of those simple ones to get the same performance? Not saying that it would be better to do that, in fact it seems redundant at too low a level. Bear in mind I don't really know what a single instruction or single clock cycle really is.

Comment: That's what an ambitious compiler's code generator should arrive at, given correct instruction descriptions. It's a challenge with assembler/machine programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to show that the answer is definitely yes (specialized hardware can beat software).

Because a software algorithm runs on a general-purpose CPU, which is a piece of hardware. So any software algorithm is at the same time a hardware one. And it can be beaten as soon as optimizations/shortcuts can be found in the implementation, which are not possible in software.

As a simple example: a floating-point multiply can be split in the product of the mantissas and the addition of the exponents; these operations have to be sequential in software, but can be (and are) performed in parallel in hardware.

Comment: Hardware parallelization is a really good simple example, are there any more simple examples of hardware-level optimizations? I really just want to move my layman's understanding to something more concrete than "custom circuit magic". Is there also significant latency in the processor reading multiple instructions to operate hardware, compared to a dedicated hardware circuit doing the exact same operations in one instruction?

Comment: `the answer is definitely yes` to *Is a specialized hardware instruction **always** faster than a software implementation*? Would you accept an implementation of a *specialized hardware instruction* in a historic commodity processor as a counterexample?

Comment: @greybeard: by my answer, a software implementation *is* a hardware implementation. Hence cannot be slower. I bet that a Babbage machine could be optimized for specific computations.

Comment: @BatWannaBe: I will not give detailed answer here. There are many ways in which the fetch-decode-execute cycle can be bypassed. Any "trick" is allowed.

Comment: I'll accept this answer for now. I did learn another search term "fetch-decode-execute", and I expect to see more examples as I read. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The Motorola 68,000 processors used to come with a co-processor for floating-point arithmetic, but also for things like logarithm, sine, cosine etc.

On the 68040 processor, the co-processor was integrated into the CPU, with the complex functions removed. The reason given was that an implementation using standard floating-point arithmetic was faster (and cheaper, obviously). It's generally very much a matter of cost.

And there is the question whether the hardware can handle parallelism well. Like two different implementations of a square root, one might be slower for one square root, but might perform multiple instructions in parallel for two or four square roots, or be able to use 512 bit vector instructions for 16 ops in parallel. The cost for 16 hardware square roots would be very high, software would be for free.